# Cost of x86 register renaming

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, renaming, register-allocation

The following code compiling with gcc or clang on amd64

```
// gcc -O2 file.c -c
int f(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return a & b & c & d;
}
```

produces following assembly:

```
0000000000000000 <f>:
  0:    89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  2:    21 c8                   and    %ecx,%eax
  4:    21 f0                   and    %esi,%eax
  6:    21 f8                   and    %edi,%eax
  8:    c3                      retq
```

As bitwise `and` should be associative one would assume it would be more efficient to accumulate pairwise into two register and then `and` those two registers. This would break a dependency and allow parallel execution on a CPU with more than one ALU.

As the compiler does `and` into the same register for all operations I am assuming that it relies on the cpu being able to do register renaming to break the dependency itself.

Does the register renaming feature of a CPU have no cost and is always available on amd64 or why do compilers compile the code like this?

**Update:**

I have found that gcc can perform the expected dependency chain breaking if one passes it a higher value for the tree-assoc-width:

```
--param tree-reassoc-width=2
```

Comment: In this case, the compiler is failing to break the dependency chain anyway. I have no idea why. So the question of renaming is moot.

Comment: it should be trivial for the compiler to break this dependency, I doubt neither gcc nor clang are able to do that. I am guessing register renaming is free so the compiler uses this code to simplify its register allocation computations

Comment: The dependency chain is still there. The CPU cannot execute each instruction until `eax` is known which depends on the previous instruction. So regardless of how the CPU renames things, it will not execute any of these in parallel.

Comment: bitwise and is associative and commutative so the compiler is free to reorder the instructions to break the dependency

Comment: I know that the compiler can re-order them to break the dependency. But looking at the assembly you gave, it clearly didn't.

Comment: And AFAIK, CPU's don't perform associativity and commutativity re-ordering optimizations.

Comment: Getting back to the core question, register renaming is an integral part of the instruction execution algorithm. So the term "cost" is somewhat undefined. Every time an instruction needs to write to a register, it pulls an empty register from the physical register file and maps it to the logical register name. (it might work slightly differently with different processors, but that's sort of the gist of it)

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it. I don't know what the callee-save registers are, but using an extra register to break the chain could require storing the register on the stack and reloading it. That would be more costly than just letting this chain just run. But on that note, why can't the compiler just smash the input registers in the first place?

Comment: No matter which way you structure it, you're still going to have 3 `and` instructions. How would you write it? The CPU probably can detect the dependency itself and forward the intermediate values in the pipeline itself. If you get switched to another core/CPU in the middle of such a trivial function, you're already paying a much higher overhead, so there's probably just not enough perceived gain to warrant such a micro optimization.

Comment: @Mysticial, I wasn't either, I had to look it up. None of the 4 registers used to pass the arguments are preserved in the linux x86-64 ABI (see Figure 3.4 in http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

Comment: Looks a missed optimization opportunity that simply doesn't have much real-world impact.

Comment: If you try it with a longer chain using more expensive instructions, the compiler might actually do something. Try chaining a bunch of multiplies. Better yet, use floating-point multiplications with `-ffast-math`.

Comment: modern cpus have 4 or more ALUs so its hardly a micro-optimization. My real case is a more complex loop and the perf profile indicates the cpu does this stuff in parallel even though the compiler writes it like this.

Comment: Can you show us such a loop? I can only guess that the CPU is reordering across loop iterations.

Comment: The processor can execute these instructions out-of-order, mixing them with instructions before and after this set.  A function like this will always be inlined.  Register renaming will come in handy for that.  The compiler plays no role in this.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like the compiler just being insufficiently clever. Although Intel's Ivy Bridge and Haswell microarchitectures support move elimination, so `mov %edx,%eax; and %ecx, %eax` would effectively become `and %ecx, %edx -->%eax`, this sequence would still take three cycles (ignoring the fact that such a small sequential dependency chain would be hidden by a modest out-of-order execution window). If the compiler were clever, something more like the following might have been generated:

```
and    %esi,%edi
and    %edx,%ecx
mov    %edi,%eax
and    %ecx,%eax
retq
```

As you noted, this would break the dependence chain. (With move elimination, the last three instruction have no data dependencies, so if the function call was an instruction [and L2 and L3 miss] and the previous instructions committed while the front-end waited for the instruction cache miss to be handled *and* a zero-overhead timer was read after the return instruction committed [assuming no target misprediction on the return] might take *one cycle* less than the code generated by gcc.) A two-wide in-order processor would execute `and %esi,%edi; and %edx,%ecx` in one cycle, `move %edi,%eax` in the next, and `and %ecx,%eax; retq` in the third, whereas for the gcc-generated code `mov %edx,%eax` would be executed in the first cycle, `and %ecx,%eax` in the second, `and %esi,%eax` in the third, and `and %edi,%eax; retq` in the fourth.

Register renaming does not break true data dependency chains but removes *name* dependencies (Write-After-Read [where the write is supposed to occur after the read, so the read gets the old value] and Write-After-Write hazards are name dependencies [technically, a write without reads could be dropped, but detecting that no reads are made *and that the later write is not speculative* is generally not considered worthwhile]; Read-After-Write is a true data dependence and Read-After-Read has no dependence). On an implementation with out-of-order execution, register renaming is part of the ordinary operation; in that sense it could be considered to have "no cost".